# TextPreview on WPF Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, custom-controls

On `Xamarin` there is a Control called `Entry`. It supports a `TextPreview` which is like a default Text to show in the "background" when a TextBox is empty.

I used [How can I add a hint text to WPF textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7433840/4610605)  to get it working on a single `TextBox`. Now I want to make this reusable (Create a `CustomControl` in `WPF`). I also tried to forge it into a global `Style` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37995806/textpreview-for-textbox) but I did't really got what i wanted. -

Long story short: **How can I get this CustomControl working ?**

I cannot get any further than this:

```
public class TextboxWithPreview : TextBox
{
    public TextboxWithPreview()
    {
        if(DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            this.TextPreview = "Default TextPreview";
        }
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextboxWithPreview), TextChangedEvent, new TextChangedEventHandler(OnTextChanged));    
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextPreviewProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextPreview", typeof(string), typeof(TextboxWithPreview));

    private static void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //pseudo Code:
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text))
        {
            this.Text = TextPreview;
            this.ForeColor = Colors.Gray;
        }
    }

    public string TextPreview
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextPreviewProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextPreviewProperty, value); }
    }        
}
```

**My thoughts about this:**

Is it possible to register a second event to an existing property ?
If so I'd like to attach my 2nd EventHandler to `TextChanged`.
As soon as the `Text`gets cleared I want the `Preview` to show up.

**To make things clear:**

I want to create a CustomControl - no workarounds.
Since it is implemented in `Xamarin.Forms.Entry` it is definedly possible.

Comment: This is called a watermark. See this question.  ^^

Comment: @LynnCrumbling well ... the Watermark story is ONE solution to get it working. As I have described above I already got it working using `Syles`. The "duplicate" you provided is not about creating a custom control.

Comment: I see multiple answers on that question that provide a solution using a Textbox-derived control. I don't think you examined all of the answers.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling yeah I saw that. Unfortunately the answer is a little old (2011)... No framework is provided there (.Net 4.0 ?! or whatever). As the comments state the provided approach is not working... That means ... I still did not get the answer I need ;( - But I really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be fighting an uphill battle trying to do this by setting your existing Text property. It may be easier to place a label over the TextBox and change it's visibility.

CustomControl's are typically styled using a [ControlTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc964292(v=vs.95).aspx), this template should be located in themes/Generic.xaml.

**TextboxWithPreview.cs**

```
public class TextboxWithPreview : TextBox
{
    private static DependencyPropertyKey HasTextPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("HasText", typeof(bool), typeof(EscapableTextBox), new PropertyMetadata());

    public static DependencyProperty HasTextProperty = HasTextPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public static DependencyProperty TextPreviewProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextPreview", typeof(string), typeof(TextboxWithPreview));

    public bool HasText
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasTextProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(HasTextPropertyKey, value); }
    }

    public string TextPreview
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextPreviewProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextPreviewProperty, value); }
    }

    static TextboxWithPreview()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextboxWithPreview), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TextboxWithPreview)));
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);

        HasText = Text.Length > 0;
    }
}
```

**Generic.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:Local="YourNamespace">

    <!-- Describes how to style a TextboxWithPreview-->
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type Local:TextboxWithPreview}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" TargetType="{x:Type Local:TextboxWithPreview}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Local:TextboxWithPreview}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Margin="2" />
                            <Label x:Name="TextPreview" Content="{Binding TextPreview, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                   FontStyle="Italic" Margin="2" Padding="2,0,0,0" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasText" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TextPreview" Value="Hidden" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: This worked for me, but TextboxWithPreview.cs is missing a dependency property for 'HasText'. After adding, override OnTextInput in TextboxWithPreview.cs and simply check if the TextCompositionEventArgs is null or empty. I would also suggest adding an additional trigger to Generic.xaml for IsFocused, to also hide the TextPreview label. Great solution, steered me perfectly!

Comment: @Brian I've added the `HasTextDependencyProperty` to my solution, good catch.